# Inheriting Mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to make a base 'Entity Schema', and other model entities would inherit from it. 
I did it, kinda, but then strange thing happened.

Those are my schemas:

- AbstractEntitySchema
- MessageSchema
- UserSchema
- RoomSchema

File: https://github.com/mihaelamj/nodechat/blob/master/models/db/mongo/schemas.js

But in MongoDB, they are all saved in the same document store: 'entity models' not separate ones, like Messages, Users..
Did I get what was supposed to happen, but not what I wanted, separate stores?
If so I will just make a basic JSON/object as entity and append the appropriate properties for each entity. Or is there a better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Discriminators`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) are a schema inheritance mechanism. They enable you to have multiple models with overlapping schemas on top of the **same underlying MongoDB collection**. rather than different documents. It seems that you misunderstand the `discriminators` of mongoose. Here is one article could help you to catch it correctly.

[Guide to mongoose discriminators](http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/07/24/guide-to-mongoose-discriminators)

---

Here are some codes sample to meet your requirement, to save the derived schema as separated documents

```
function AbstractEntitySchema() {   
    //call super        
    Schema.apply(this, arguments);     
    //add                                     
    this.add({                              
        entityName: {type: String, required: false},
        timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        index: {type: Number, required: false},
        objectID: {type: String},
        id: {type: String}
    });                                     
};
util.inherits(AbstractEntitySchema, Schema);

//Message Schema
var MessageSchema = new AbstractEntitySchema();
MessageSchema.add({
    text: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: false}
});

//Room Schema
var RoomSchema = new AbstractEntitySchema();
RoomSchema.add({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: String, required: false},
    messages : [MessageSchema],
});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
var Room = mongoose.model('Room', RoomSchema);

// save data to Message and Room

var aMessage = new Message({
     entityName: 'message',
     text: 'Hello',
     author: 'mmj',
     type: 'article'
    });

 var aRoom = new Room({
     entityName: 'room',
     name: 'Room1',
     author: 'mmj',
     type: 'article'
 });

 aRoom.save(function(err, myRoom) { 
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else                                  
        console.log("room is saved"); 
 });

 aMessage.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('user is saved');
 });
```

Comment: does that add object to separate message collection how can we use same collection for all objects

Answer (score 11):

If you want multiple overlapping models with **different MongoDB collections**, then you use this approach:

```
function extendSchema (Schema, definition, options) {
  return new mongoose.Schema(
    Object.assign({}, Schema.obj, definition),
    options
  );
}
```

Example

```
const extendSchema = require('mongoose-extend-schema');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {type: String},
  lastname: {type: String}
});

const ClientSchema = extendSchema(UserSchema, {
  phone: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

You simply extend the original object the schema was created with and recreate a new schema on its basis. This is some sort of abstract schema which you inherit from.

Check this npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-extend-schema

Comment: Brilliant, this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Far more suitable for my usecase compared to discrimators. All my objects in the db inherit from CommonMetadata `export var ImageSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    isMock: Boolean,
    isActive: Boolean,
    created: Date,
    updated: Date,
});` Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

Since ES6 this works as well:

```
var ImageSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    ...CommonMetadataSchema.obj,
    src: String,
    description: String,
});
```

Comment: This isn't ES6, looks like Typescript or something.

Comment: @mikinoidea That's a spread operator ... it doesn't spread the methods attached to the schema though

Comment: The [`Spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operation DOES work if the `...CommonMetadataSchema` is just a JSON object and not a mongoose schema object.