# "Base schema" returns only one type instead of 2 (mongodb - mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I tried to implement basic schemas inheritance with mongoose.
Based on http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator and https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/1647 and [Inheriting Mongoose schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361297/inheriting-mongoose-schemas).

When I try to .find() on Person, it only gives me back Employees, which is a problem to me since I am expecting Employees and Volunteers.

The schemas :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var util = require('util');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function BaseSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  });
}
util.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);

var PersonSchema = new BaseSchema();
var EmployeeSchema = new BaseSchema();
EmployeeSchema.add({department: String});
var VolunteerSchema = new BaseSchema();
VolunteerSchema.add({shop: String});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
var Volunteer = Person.discriminator('volunteer', VolunteerSchema);
var Employee = Person.discriminator('employee', EmployeeSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Volunteer', VolunteerSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```

How I try to get volunteers and employees :

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Person = require('../models/person.js');

// ...

  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Person.find({}, function (err, persons) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(persons);
  });
});
```

How I added 'fixtures'

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Person = require('../models/person.js'),
  Employee = mongoose.model('Employee'),
  Volunteer = mongoose.model('Volunteer');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbname')
    .then(function() {
        console.log('connection to db successful');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

Employee.create([
  {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Steinbeck',
    department: 'Deprimos',
    created_at: Date.Now
  }, {
    firstname: 'Terry',
    lastname: 'Pratchett',
    department: 'Fun',
    created_at: Date.Now
  }, {
    firstname: 'Frank',
    lastname: 'Herbert',
    department: 'Mindblowing',
    created_at: Date.Now
  }, {
    firstname: 'George R.R.',
    lastname: 'Martin',
    department: 'Sadistic',
    created_at: Date.Now
  }
], function(err, person) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(person);
});

Volunteer.create([
  {
    firstname: 'Zekiya',
    lastname: 'Orson',
    shop: 'Shop 1',
    created_at: Date.Now
  }, {
    firstname: 'Gazorp',
    lastname: 'Azorp',
    shop: 'Shop 2',
    created_at: Date.Now
  }
], function(err, person) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(person);
});
```

Thanks for any lead/clue/solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Seems I messed/mixed up a bit.
Bad exports, bad imports.

Maybe it would help someone :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var util = require('util');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function PersonSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  });
}
util.inherits(PersonSchema, Schema);

var personSchema = new PersonSchema();

var employeeSchema = new PersonSchema();
employeeSchema.add({department: String});

var volunteerSchema = new PersonSchema();
volunteerSchema.add({shop: String});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
var Volunteer = Person.discriminator('volunteer', volunteerSchema);
var Employee = Person.discriminator('employee', employeeSchema);

module.exports = {
    Person: Person,
    Volunteer : Volunteer,
    Employee : Employee
};
```

and to retrieve :

```
var PersonModel = require('../models/person.model');

personsRouter.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  PersonModel.Person.find({}, function(err, employees) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(employees);
  });
});
```