# Add ownership to mongoose documents

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

What is the preferred way to add ownership to mongoose documents? I've had a look at schema inheritance [using discriminators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361297/inheriting-mongoose-schemas), but what if the models are really different from one another? Like a `House` and a `Car`? Both should have owners, but they vary widely in most other respects.

Is there a best-practice for modeling this? I'm planning to write some middleware to populate the documents, but right now I'm kinda stuck at the modeling stage. I'm using mongoosejs and express for my infrastructure.