# NestJS Mongoose Schema Inheritence

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am attempting to inherit Mongoose Schemas or SchemaDefitions within NestJS but I am not having much luck.
I am doing this so I can share Base and Common Schema Definition Details such as a virtual('id') and a nonce, we have attached to each of the entities. Each schema definition should have its own collection in Mongo, so discriminators will not work.

I tried to implement this in the following different ways

First, I have the following Base Schema Definition defined:

**base.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { TimeStamps } from './timestamps.schema';

export type BaseDocument = BaseSchemaDefinition & Document;

@Schema({
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc: any, ret: any) {
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
      return ret;
    },
  },
})
export class BaseSchemaDefinition {
  @Prop({
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    default: Types.ObjectId,
  })
  nonce: Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  timestamps: TimeStamps;
}
```

I then inherit the schema definition and create the schema so it can be used later in my services and controllers by the following:

**person.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Address } from './address.schema';
import { BaseSchemaDefinition } from './base.schema';

export type PersonDocument = PersonSchemaDefintion & Document;

export class PersonSchemaDefintion extends BaseSchemaDefinition {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  first_name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  last_name: string;

  @Prop()
  middle_name: string;

  @Prop()
  data_of_birth: Date;

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' }] })
  addresses: [Address];
}

const PersonSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(PersonSchemaDefintion);

PersonSchema.virtual('id').get(function (this: PersonDocument) {
  return this._id;
});

export { PersonSchema };
```

This results in only allowing me to create and get properties defined in the BaseSchemaDefinition.

> {
> "timestamps": {
> "deleted": null,
> "updated": "2021-09-21T16:55:17.094Z",
> "created": "2021-09-21T16:55:17.094Z"
> },
> "_id": "614a0e75eb6cb52aa0ccd026",
> "nonce": "614a0e75eb6cb52aa0ccd028",
> "__v": 0 }

Second, I then tried to implement inheritance by using the method described here
[Inheriting Mongoose schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361297/inheriting-mongoose-schemas) (different MongoDB collections)

**base.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { TimeStamps } from './timestamps.schema';

export type BaseDocument = BaseSchemaDefinition & Document;

@Schema({
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc: any, ret: any) {
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
      return ret;
    },
  },
})
export class BaseSchemaDefinition {
  @Prop({
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    default: Types.ObjectId,
  })
  nonce: Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  timestamps: TimeStamps;
}

const BaseSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(BaseSchemaDefinition);

BaseSchema.virtual('id').get(function (this: BaseDocument) {
  return this._id;
});

export { BaseSchema };
```

**person.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Address } from './address.schema';
import { BaseSchema, BaseSchemaDefinition } from './base.schema';

export type PersonDocument = PersonSchemaDefintion & Document;

export class PersonSchemaDefintion extends BaseSchemaDefinition {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  first_name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  last_name: string;

  @Prop()
  middle_name: string;

  @Prop()
  data_of_birth: Date;

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' }] })
  addresses: [Address];
}

export const PersonSchema = Object.assign(
  {},
  BaseSchema.obj,
  PersonSchemaDefintion,
);
```

Results in the same output. Not sure why the inheritance is not taking

The following is the service code that uses the schemas and builds the models

**person.service.ts**

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {
  PersonSchemaDefintion,
  PersonDocument,
} from 'src/schemas/person.schema';
import { TimeStamps } from 'src/schemas/timestamps.schema';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(PersonSchemaDefintion.name)
    private personModel: Model<PersonDocument>,
  ) {}

  async create(
    personModel: PersonSchemaDefintion,
  ): Promise<PersonSchemaDefintion> {
    personModel.timestamps = new TimeStamps();
    const createdPerson = new this.personModel(personModel);

    return createdPerson.save();
  }

  async update(
    id: string,
    changes: Partial<PersonSchemaDefintion>,
  ): Promise<PersonSchemaDefintion> {
    const existingPerson = this.personModel
      .findByIdAndUpdate(id, changes)
      .exec()
      .then(() => {
        return this.personModel.findById(id);
      });
    if (!existingPerson) {
      throw Error('Id does not exist');
    }
    return existingPerson;
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<PersonSchemaDefintion[]> {
    return this.personModel.find().exec();
  }

  async findOne(id: string): Promise<PersonSchemaDefintion> {
    return this.personModel.findById(id).exec();
  }

  async delete(id: string): Promise<string> {
    return this.personModel.deleteOne({ _id: id }).then(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(`${id} has been deleted`);
    });
  }
}
```

I can provide additional details if it is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around with it for a while I found the right combination that appears to work when leveraging these technologies

Here is the base class

**base.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { TimeStamps } from './timestamps.schema';

export type BaseDocument = Base & Document;

@Schema()
export class Base {
  @Prop({
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    default: Types.ObjectId,
  })
  nonce: Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  timestamps: TimeStamps;
}
```

Here is the class that inherits the base.schema

**person.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { Address } from './address.schema';
import { Base } from './base.schema';

export type PersonDocument = Person & Document;

@Schema({
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc: any, ret: any) {
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
      return ret;
    },
  },
})
export class Person extends Base {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  first_name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  last_name: string;

  @Prop()
  middle_name: string;

  @Prop()
  data_of_birth: Date;

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' }] })
  addresses: [Address];
}
const PersonSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Person);

PersonSchema.virtual('id').get(function (this: PersonDocument) {
  return this._id;
});

export { PersonSchema };
```

The only thing I would like to improve on is moving the virtual('id') to the base class. However the schema inheritance does not work. At this point, it will only work with the Schema Definition. This at least gets me in the right direction. If anyone has a way to improve on this please contribute.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have same issue.

This is my solution:

First, you need custom @Schema decorator.

**schema.decorator.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { TypeMetadataStorage } from '@nestjs/mongoose/dist/storages/type-metadata.storage';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export type SchemaOptions = mongoose.SchemaOptions & {
    inheritOption?: boolean
}

function mergeOptions(parentOptions: SchemaOptions, childOptions: SchemaOptions) {
    for (const key in childOptions) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(childOptions, key)) {
            parentOptions[key] = childOptions[key];
        }
    }
    return parentOptions;
}

export function Schema(options?: SchemaOptions): ClassDecorator {
    return (target: Function) => {
        const isInheritOptions = options.inheritOption;

        if (isInheritOptions) {
            let parentOptions = TypeMetadataStorage.getSchemaMetadataByTarget((target as any).__proto__).options;
            parentOptions = _.cloneDeep(parentOptions)  
            options = mergeOptions(parentOptions, options);
        }

        TypeMetadataStorage.addSchemaMetadata({
            target,
            options
        })
    }
}
```

This is base schema.

**cat.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Schema } from '../../common/decorators/schema.decorator'
import { Document } from "mongoose";

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema({
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
        transform: function (doc: any, ret: any) {
            delete ret._id;
            delete ret.__v;
            return ret;
        },
    },
})
export class Cat {
    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    age: number;

    @Prop()
    breed: string;
}

const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);

CatSchema.virtual("id").get(function (this: CatDocument) {
    return this._id;
});

export { CatSchema };
```

**england-cat.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Schema } from "../../common/decorators/schema.decorator";
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { Cat } from "../../cats/schemas/cat.schema";

export type EnglandCatDocument = EnglandCat & Document;

@Schema({
    inheritOption: true
})
export class EnglandCat extends Cat {
    @Prop()
    numberLegs: number;
}

export const EnglandCatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(EnglandCat)
```

EnglandCat is subclass of Cat and it inherits all options from Cat, you can overwrite some options if you want.

Comment: I will test this out when I can. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

those Hieu Cao answer's is correct because the question is "Schema Inheritance".  Your checked answer doesn't related about extending schema, it's about basic inherit class, you doesn't have any schema options in Base.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33324286)